# Making asynchronous (node.js) in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

Some questions about Meteor and node.js:

Meteor is based on node.js, but can we do node.js IN meteor? (or use it with meteor?)

I would like to combine the power of two and make this (for exemple): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqWD1WGrdjw, in/coupled with meteor...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to do async stuff. You need to use Fibers (node-fibers) inside Meteor. There are great screencasts from cmather explaining them:

1. http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/nodejs-introducing-fibers
2. http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/nodejs-using-futures

Comment: Thank you. I knew that meteor was based on fiber ans SockJS but I didn't know that it was as helpful. Only 2 other question : 1)can we use asyn(js) insted of fiber for this case and 2) can we use socket.io in meteor or it is SockJS too ?

Comment: 1) Meteor is built on top of Fibers, so I don't think so. But I'm not a Node expert
2) Don't know